# Como modificar variables de sesión en express dentro de funciones asíncronas

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, async-await, async

estoy programando una web en node con express, y necesito modificar una variable de sesión, mi código para modificarla es el siguiente:

```
funcion_prueba(1).then(ok => { 
     return req.session.usuario[0].id = 'ok'; 
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('error:', err);
});
```

pero si saco con un console.log el req.session.usuario veo que el id no ha cambiado, la funcion_prueba solamente retorna un 1, este es solamente un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer, pero no logro hacer que dentro de una función asíncrona se modifique mi variable de sesión, ¿Alguien sabe como podría hacerlo? Muchas gracias.

Comment: La variable se modifica, lo que no estarás haciendo es comprobando esta modificación en el sitio (momento) correcto. Pero sin ver esa comprobación, es complicado ayudarte

Comment: Si, dentro del then si que se modifica, pero quiero que se modifique fuera

Comment: Tu problema es de asincronía. La función que llamas `funcion_prueba` devuelve una Promesa (o eso se desprende del poco código aportado). Tienes 2 opciones: mueves toda la lógica que hay al hacer el cambio para que continúe dentro del método `then`, o bien haces que el entorno donde es llamada la función sea un entorno tipo `async` para que puedas usar la sentencia `await` delante del llamado a tu función. En cualquier caso, nunca podrás *sacar* el resultado del cambio fuera del proceso asíncrono, debido a la naturaleza del mismo. Saludos